# ExpressJS - Load partial view from other folder

Tags: express

In my views folder, I've got a folder called "events"
In here, I've got a template: **register.ejs**

In my views folder, there's another folder called **members**, with a view called **register_profile**

In events/register.ejs, I have:

```
<%-partial('/views/members/register_profile', {locals: {stuff: things}})%>
```

However, on running the app, I get:
failed to locate view "members/register_profile"

I've tried all kinds of variations of path with no effect...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry...
from the docs..

```
<%-partial('../members/register_profile', {locals: {stuff: things}})%>
```

i missed the ../ part